# Update field of database

Tags: magento, magento-2.3

I have this code to udpdate max length  of an attribute

```
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if ($context->getVersion()
            && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2') < 0
        ) {
            $table = $setup->getTable('eav_attribute');
            $setup->getConnection()
                ->update($table, ['frontend_class' => 'validate-length maximum-length-70'], 'attribute_id = 73');
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

It works fine bu instad of attribute_id = 73 I want to put attribute_code= name but it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to put attribute_code= name but it does not work." What have you tried, and how exactly does it not work?

Comment: I want to update database field where attribute_code= name instead of using attribute_id = xx in upgradedata.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    
    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
         $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if ($context->getVersion()
            && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2') < 0
        ) {
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $this->eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                'catalog_product',
                'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_GOES_HERE',
                'frontend_class',
                'validate-length maximum-length-70'
            );
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Watch out for typos. I didn't check the code.

Comment: I don't understand your question. In case you are asking what the code does, it updates the field `frontend_class` for the product attribute with the code `ATTRIBUTE_CODE_GOES_HERE`.

Comment: But in my case I want to update just frontend_class where attribute_code=name. Can you help?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what the code does. but it doesn'd do it through a direct query. it does it in the recommended way, via the internal flow. this eventually translates into a query like you tried, but it has some extra security measures

Comment: So if I use your code I have to put name instead of ATTRIBUTE_CODE_GOES_HERE?